# glusterfs 3.2.5 transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: glusterfs

I have been trying to setup a mirror across 2 servers with gluster (3.2.5) on ubuntu 12.04 for a day or so now and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have a openvpn tunnel between the two vps

Currently there are no iptables rules for the openvpn interfaces

I setup an initial volume using the following command:

```
gluster volume create vmail replica 2 transport tcp gserver1:/var/export/vmail gserver2:/var/export/vmail
```

I mounted using this command:

```
mount.glusterfs gserver1:/vmail /var/vmail
```

I get this error:

```
~# df -h
df: `/var/vmail': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I see the following errors in the brick log file which I have googled but to be honest can't find anything that looks very useful:

```
I [glusterfsd.c:1493:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfsd: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfsd version 3.2.5
W [socket.c:419:__socket_keepalive] 0-socket: failed to set keep idle on socket 8
W [socket.c:1846:socket_server_event_handler] 0-socket.glusterfsd: Failed to set keep-alive: Operation not supported
W [graph.c:291:gf_add_cmdline_options] 0-vmail-server: adding option 'listen-port' for volume 'vmail-server' with value '24009'
W [rpc-transport.c:447:validate_volume_options] 0-tcp.vmail-server: option 'listen-port' is deprecated, preferred is 'transport.socket.listen-port', continuing with correction
C [posix.c:4723:init] 0-vmail-posix: Extended attribute not supported, exiting.
E [xlator.c:1447:xlator_init] 0-vmail-posix: Initialization of volume 'vmail-posix' failed, review your volfile again
E [graph.c:348:glusterfs_graph_init] 0-vmail-posix: initializing translator failed
E [graph.c:526:glusterfs_graph_activate] 0-graph: init failed
W [glusterfsd.c:727:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/lib/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_handle_reply+0xa5) [0x7f5c1ebaeec5] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfsd(mgmt_getspec_cbk+0xc7) [0x7f5c1f246c07] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfsd(glusterfs_process_volfp+0x192) [0x7f5c1f244b52]))) 0-: received signum (0), shutting down
```

Can someone help me to fix this? All I want is 2 way replication (HA) across these 2 servers.

Comment: when you ran your create command what did gluster say? Creation of volume "vmail" has been successful. Please start the volume to access data.

Comment: I did start the volume. I just did not write that in here.

And yes, gluster reported the creation of the volume as successful.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in an update:

- I have since does some testing on a couple of test virtual box instances.
- I setup the OpenVPN between the two, same as in the real setup.
- I setup the gluster volumes in the same way, and it all works.

I tried to replicate the exact steps on the real environment and it does not.

It seems to be a tuning issue on the OpenVZ containers, and I have opened a couple of support tickets with them requesting certain tuning parameters I found on another post.

I will update this thread once I have confirmed whether that tuning does or does not work.

J

Comment: what is the update here?